# SetValue in Swift from Firebase removes old value's

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the documentation it says that I should use this code to set new value's:

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": username])
```

This way, I can set an username. However, if I want to add another value later on, like XP points, I use the following line of code:

```
var XPPoints = 1    
self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["XPPoints": XPPoints])
```

This, however, deletes the username value, or any other value that was stored before. It replaces all value's.
I tried also the second thing the docs are saying at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#basic_write which is this line of code:

```
self.ref.child("users/(user.uid)/username").setValue(username)
```

This will crash my app instantly when starting up. My question is: How can I add data, and not replacing the old value's?

Edit:
Fixed it by changing the code to:
self.ref.child("users/\(user.uid)/username").setValue(username)

Comment: `user.uid` should be replaced by the real value. The doc either means this is a placeholder, or it has an error for the example. Try this: `self.ref.child("users/\(user.uid)/username").setValue(username)`. In this way the proper user uid will be fed, so the actual path would be something like "users/100/username".

Comment: Meh, I am such a noob. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Your solution shouldn't fix the problem you are having. You need to use `updateChildValues` instead of `setValue`. This adds the values instead of overwriting everything in the referenced node.

Comment: How do you mean? And why would I use that and when? The setValue works good for me...

Comment: You mention in your question that setValue replaces all the other values that were already set, correct?